# AlertDialog restarted each time I return to MainActivity

Tags: android, service, android-alertdialog, android-activity

I created a MainActivity in which the user has a few app options, displayed in a grid menu, which access subsequent specific activities. However, when the application starts, I use an AlertDialog for the user to enter login details, inflated just after the grid layout definition.
The problem is, each time I select an item in the grid menu (and, consequently, a new activity), the AlertDialog pops-up again. How can I avoid this?

Moreover, I have an uploading service which should start with the beginning of the MainActivity (or after the login, perhaps), but should not be restarted each time a new activity is called. I assume this problem is related to the previous one, although I have managed to temporarily solve it by using a startService button via an OptionsMenu. This is no permanent solution.

Thank you in advance.

**EDIT:** I tried to use getSharedPreferences as follows:

```
private SharedPreferences prefs;
private String prefName = "MyPref";
int hasLoggedIn;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.mm_gridmenu);

    SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(prefName, MODE_PRIVATE);
    hasLoggedIn = prefs.getInt("hasLoggedIn", 0);

    if (hasLoggedIn == 0) {
        showDialog(SHOW_DIALOG);
        prefs = getSharedPreferences(prefName , MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
        editor.putInt("hasLoggedIn", 1);
        editor.commit();
    }
```

However, this way the hasLoggedIn value is saved as 1 and the dialog never pops-up again. I tried setting the back button to fix that, but this seems to prevent the app from being minimized. Is there a way to add that action to the button? (Which I would duplicate on the Home button as well)

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    prefs = getSharedPreferences(prefName , MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
    editor.putInt("hasLoggedIn", 0);
    editor.commit();
    Log.i("hasLoggedIn", hasLoggedIn + "");
    return;
}
```

Moreover, I believe this action will affect subsequent activities (setting the alertDialog back on). Which should be a valid alternative to this?

Comment: Paste your code... we can't predict how to solve your problem without it.

Comment: @Cristian, do you have any suggestions after viewing the code? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you need to keep track of your applications states, you have a few options to do this. One simple way would be to use a `SharedPreferences` to store a boolean variable called something like `hasLoggedIn`  after the user logs in you set this value to `true`. Each time your main activity launches simply check the value of `hasLoggedIn` if its is set to `false` require the user log in again.  If it is already true don't show the log in dialog

Comment: That's a great idea, how have I not thought of that?! Thank you, I'll try that!

Comment: I clearly have not yet mastered sharedPreferences. I will edit my question with the present code.

Comment: can you help me with the new problem? @slayton

Comment: @Cath If you want your app to quit on the `onBackPressed` method you must tell the app that. You've overridden the default `onPressedMethod`. To close your `Activity` when the back button is pressed simply add a call to `finish()` in your `onBackPressed()` method

Comment: If I finish this activity, that would kill the service I want to keep running in the background as well, right? I just wanted to change the hasLoggedIn to false to demand the login when the app is opened again. Furthermore, this does not solve the problem I am having with the Activities called by the Main one, because the OnBackPressed defined will set the hasLoggedIn to false each time I return to the MainActivity. @slayton

Comment: @Cath, no services are independent from Activities, they have their own life cycle and are killed separately from the activities that spawn them

Comment: Oh, great, I did not know that. On the other hand, if I reopen the app, which starts the service, will there be two equal services or android detects one is already running? And what about the onBackPressed if I am not on the MainActivity, will it close the secondary activity? I still am not sure what is the best approach to change the hasLoggedIn only if the app is minimized/closed. @slayton

Comment: @Cath, we're really getting off topic here, its probably better you start a new question about services

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:
Add a boolean flag in your MainActivity:

```
private boolean dialogFlag = true;
```

in the onCreate/onResume method:

```
if(dialogFlag) {
    createDialog();
    dialogFlag = false;
}
```

If you want to pop up just once the app is installed, you can save this flag into a property file. And read it first whenever the app is getting started.

Comment: This won't work if the MainActivity object is destroyed before the activity resumed, as a new object will be generated and the flag will be the default value of `true`.

Comment: Yes, if that happens you should may create a manager class which holds states alive.

Comment: Why do that when the `SharedPrefernces` already exist to do just this?